# Как узнать размер выделенного текста RichTextBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите, как узнать размер выделенного текста в RichTextBox WPF.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: размер шрифта, высоту, ширину, или что?

Comment: Прошу прощение, что не уточнил. К примеру взять Word, если нажать на определённое слово или строку, то в панели возле графы со шрифтами отобразится размер текста(к примеру 14). Мне нужно реализовать подобное